# How to stop a partition move early

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm using GParted to try to add some free space to the beginning of a large drive. The partition was 415 GB, and I set GParted in motion to shrink it to 365 GB and move it to the right, giving me 50 GB of unallocated space at the beginning of the drive.

Only 33 gigabytes of the 415 GB partition are actually used, and yet GParted is taking forever copying all of the empty space over to its new position. So far, 144 GB of 365 GB have been copied, and it estimates another 7 hours or so.

My question is this: I know that the data is continuous and at the beginning of the partition, as I recently (yesterday) wiped the partition and wrote the data there. Since it has already copied 144 GB of the data, I feel pretty confident that the 33 GB that is actually used has already been copied.

Is there a way I can speed things up, i.e. cancel the operation and write the partition table manually with the block # and sizes and the like? The data in the partition is not mission critical - if I lose it it'd be a pain, but not the end of the world, so I'm willing to try risky maneuvers.

Answer (score 0):

I (think) GParted is moving every single bit over to the right, which will take forever with a few hundred gigabytes. You could speed the process up by simply backing up the small amount of files, reformatting and recreating the partitions, and moving back. Probably it would have been better since starting afresh is always good.

Just a note: Do NOT interrupt GParted! Doing so will most likely corrupt your partition table or other important disk parts.

Comment: I guess what I should have done was shrunk the partition down to 33 gigs, THEN moved it, then re-expanded it. Oh well, lesson learned. What I was getting at was that some people have been able to recover partitions after failure mid-move (i.e. power outage, etc) using some kind of free software. I was wondering if I could cancel it and just do that, or manually write the partition table somehow, since all the data had already been moved and it was just copying blank space now.